# Open POS-tagged .txt-file with tags in python

Tags: python, nltk, part-of-speech

I'm trying to POS-tag a bunch of interviews in German. I've been getting great results with the "ClassifierBasedGermanTagger" using the Tiger-Corpus. I saved the tagged results as .txt files, but due to some issues regarding the quality of the transcriptions i wanna go back to the files and make some revisions to the words or tags. Is there an easy way to do this in python?

So far i tried the `nltk.corpus.reader function`, but i was'nt even shure if it's the proper function to do this. i got a little further with str2tuple function using the code:

```
[nltk.tag.str2tuple(t) for t in sent.split()]
```

but it would allways splitt words and tags

This is the format of the .txt file:

('word', 'tag'),('word', 'tag'), ('word', 'tag'), ...

Comment: Looking at the source code doe str2tuple the input should be something like word/tag. In your example, split on '), (', then remove all remaining parentheses and single quotation marks. Finally, you have your input for str2tuple with sep=','.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast reply. I was somehow able to read it into python. But after looking tuples up again, i realised that i could'nt do any revisions after converting the split to tuples. Also i'm not shure about my code to remove parentheses and quotation marks, i'm afraid it might ruin the format. I used something like this:

tagged=sent.split("), (")
for i in tagged:
    i.replace("(","")
    i.replace(")","")
    i.replace("'","")